# Grid in Visual Studio Crystal Report by SAP

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, crystal-reports

I want to add a data table or grid in crystal report, it can be empty, but i need it, with 6 rows and 4 columns.

I can draw it using lines, but i expect that crystal report might have some table or grid.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to use a cross tab for that.

There are some [videos](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Vp3_Vy1eSXo) on YouTube demonstrating cross tabs in Crystal Reports.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a blank grid I think you are going to have to draw it on the form. You don't mention the version of Crystal Reports that you are using but there is no table or grid controls in any of the recent versions of Crystal Reports.